# How can I join a vector with commas

Tags: r

```
b = c(1,1,1,1)
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

What can I do to change `b` into `"1,1,1,1"`

Answer (score 2):

Use `paste0` setting `collapse=","`

```
> paste0(b, collapse=",")
[1] "1,1,1,1"
```

Note that the result is not longer numeric, it's character.

`cat` is another alternative

```
> cat(b, sep=",")
1,1,1,1
```

as pointed out by @digEmAll, you can not store the output of  `cat` since it only prints the output on the console, if you want to capture that output to store it in an object, then one alternative is using `capture.output` as in:

```
capture.output (cat(b, sep=","))
```

which is the same result provided by `paste0` above.

Comment: Note that `cat` does not return anything, is just a function that prints on the console, while `paste`/`paste0` return an object of type character.